# Eclipse error: "Errors running builder on project. Path must include project and resource name..."

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project
>   'BaseGameUtils'.
>
> Path must include project and resource name: /BaseGameUtils
>
> Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project
>   'google-play-services_lib'.
>
> Path must include project and resource name: /google-play-services_lib
>
> Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'metric'.
>
> Path must include project and resource name: /metric

I'm trying to build my project but keep getting the above errors. What do they mean? Which path needs to include project and resource name?

Thanks

Comment: The messages include the paths in error - `/BaseGameUtils`, `/google-play-services_lib` and `/metric` all these should be in the form `/project/path`

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for your reply, how should I fix this? Do I create a directory inside which I put the 3 different folders?